# How to make QDialog to be modal only for its non-modal parent window, but not for the all grandparent ones?

Tags: qt

It is required for the project, I'm currently working on, to have a non-modal dialog (let's call it dialog "A") which pops up another dialog(let's call it dialog "B") which would be a modal one but only for its parent (dialog "A"). So, when dialog "B" is popped up it should block only the dialog "A" whereas the rest of the GUI should not be blocked. The Main Window is the parent of dialog "A" whereas dialog "A" is the parent of dialog "B" and these parent-child relationships cannot be changed.

Does anyone have some idea how this can be achieved?

I've tried to achieve this by relying on a [Qt::WindowModality](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qt.html#WindowModality-enum) property. For the dialog "A" it is set on [Qt::NonModal](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qt.html#WindowModality-enum) value whereas for the dialog "B" it is set on [Qt::WindowModal](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qt.html#WindowModality-enum) one. Both dialogs are popped up by calling QWidget::show(), but when the dialog "B" is shown it blocks both Main Window and dialog "A". Having Main Window blocked the whole GUI practically becomes blocked which collides with our requirements.

According to Qt documentation for the [Qt::WindowModality](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qt.html#WindowModality-enum) property, the behavior we just faced with is expected because it is stated there that the [Qt::WindowModal](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qt.html#WindowModality-enum) value makes the window modal for its parent window and all grandparents ones. In my opinion, this feature of making a window modal for all its grandparents, no matter if some window in the parent-child chain is a non-modal one, seems like a lack in the logic of the [Qt::WindowModality](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qt.html#WindowModality-enum) property. It would be logical to break this cycle after the first parent/grandparent in a chain that is shown as non-modal one.

Comment: have you tried creating your first dialog (Dialog A) without giving it a parent ? Just an idea. Not sure this will work.

Comment: Hi basslo, thank you for the suggestion. Yes, leaving Dialog A without parent will make the rest of the GUI non-blocking when the Dialog B is popped up. This is something that we already did as an initial solution, but it has one drawback, at least in the term of our project specification. This way both Dialogs A i B will be sent behind to the task bar when whatever part of the GUI, other than these two dialogs, is pressed. According to our project spec. these two dialogs should be sent behind and raised in the front only by clicking on some toggle button.

Comment: when instantiating your Dialog try using Qt::Dialog| Qt::WindowStaysOnTopHint for Qt::WindowFlags

Comment: Hi basslo, thanks again for the help. You proposal with Qt::Dialog | Qt::WindowsStaysOnTopHint will do the job, but it will introduce another issue in our project. We have a lot of other non-related dialogs with those mentioned in this particular problem. If our Dialog would be set on the top, in that case all other non-related dialogs will be covered, partially or completely, when they would pop up. What's worse, if they are modal, we will end up in a situation to have completely non-responsive GUI because they expect some input, but cannot get it in situation when they are completely covered

Answer (score 2):

I faced this issue in my project, and the best workaround that I found in almost one research week was to disable the parent window with:

```cpp
parent.setEnable(false);
```

But this method affects the widget and all children[[1]](https://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.8/qwidget.html#enabled-prop), so you need to enable all children before show the window:

```cpp
child.setEnabled(true); 
child.show();
```

The main drawback is that you can close the parent window. But a workaround is if you inherit from your parent widget, you can override the close button's method and check if the child is enabled with `isEnabled()` before close.